# Eclipse + tomcat rest application 404 though server and services are running

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8

I need help on this. If I deploy the code manually application is reachable, endpoints working fine, but throws 404 when I deploy from eclipse. I changed property of tomcat from workspace metadata to /servers tomcat v8.0, changed the server location to "Use Tomcat Installation" on server overview. I even tried with copying ROOT folder from tomcat installation folder/webapps to wtpwebapps though it existed there.

Donno what else I can do. I can see server welcome page. I can access service endpoints when I manually deploy in same server but not after publish from tomcat. I seek some help on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Project: Properties-> Java Build Path-> Add Library -> Select "Server Runtime" from the list-> Next->Select "Apache Tomcat"-> Finish

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, even removed project added again, restarted server, didn't help